# Get the number of columns in an ASCII file

Tags: perl, ascii

I have found many questions regarding CSV files, but not regarding a normal ASCII file (`.dat`) file.

Assuming I have a subroutine `sub writeMyFile($data)`, which writes different values in an ASCII file `my_file.dat`. Each column is then a value, which I want to plot in another subroutine `sub plotVals()`, but for that I need to know the number of columns of  `my_file.dat`, which is not always the same.

**What is an easy an readable way in Perl to have the number of columns of an ASCII file `my_file.dat`?**

Some sample input/output would be (note: file might have multiple rows):

In:

```
(first line on my_data1.dat) -19922 233.3442    12312 0 0
(first line on my_data2.dat) 0 0 0
```

Out:

```
(for my_data1.dat) 5
(for my_data2.dat) 3
```

Comment: Do you mean how many characters wide is each line?  Could you provide an example input/output?

Comment: Modify `writeMyFile` to add the number of columns as the first line of the file?

Comment: @xxfelixxx sorry, you are right! I added 2 dummy examples. I assume that the file is fully populated (so there are no measurements missing in lower rows), and probably an empty file should return `0` or `undef`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't really given us enough detail for any answer to be really helpful (explaining the format of your data file, for example, would have been a great help).

But let's assume that you have a file where the fields are separated by whitespace - something like this:

```
col1  col2 col3    col4   col5 col6 col7    col8
```

We know nothing about the columns, only that they are separated by varying amounts of white space.

We can open the file in the usual manner.

```
my $file = 'my_file.dat';
open my $data_fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
```

We can read each record from the file in turn in the usual manner.

```
while (<$data_fh>) {
  # Data is in $_. Let's remove the newline from the end.
  chomp;
  # Here we do other interesting stuff with the data...
}
```

Probably, a useful thing to do would be to split the record so that each field is stored in a separate element of an array. That's simple with [`split()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

```
# By default, split() works on $_ and splits on whitespace, so this is
# equivalent to:
# my @data = split /\s+/, $_;
my @data = split;
```

Now we get to your question. We have all of our values in `@data`. But we don't know how many values there are. Luckily, Perl makes it simple to find out the number of elements in an array. We just assign the array to a scalar variable.

```
my $number_of_values = @data;
```

I think that's all the information you'll need. Depending on the actual format of your data file, you might need to change the `split()` line in some way - but without more information it's impossible for us to know what you need there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I have provided some dummy examples in the original question.
We can probably assume that the file is fully populated (so there are no measurements missing in lower rows), and that an empty file should return `0`, `undef` or something similar

Comment: Ok, it looks like my guess at your format was correct. So something based on my code will work. Happy I could help.

Comment: Just one follow-up question. What if the file has leading spaces? In that case the regex would think there is one extra character in the file, am I correct? Is there an easy way to overcome this edge-case?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? As a programmer, you should be able to either read the documentation for the `split` function or devise a simple test to find out what happens. Can you explain this - `perl -E'$_=" a b c"; @a=split; say scalar @a'`?

Answer (score 0):

When reading the file in `plotVals()`, split each line on whatever delimiter you use in the data file, and count how many fields you get. I presume that you have to split the lines anyway to plot the individual data points, unless you call an external utility for doing the plotting. If you call an external utility for plotting, then it is enough to read one representative row (the first?) and count the fields in that.

Alternatively pass the data or some meta data (the number of columns) directly to `plotVals()`.